# I m confused about the contain part. I want to check if in greet ''contains: [] - list of symbols that an argument should contain''?

Tags: python, python-3.x

''''''
QUESTION:
Write a decorator `arg_rules` that validates arguments passed to the function.

A decorator should take 3 arguments:

max_length: 15

type_: str

contains: [] - list of symbols that an argument should contain

If some of the rules' checks returns False, the function should return False and print the reason it failed; otherwise, return the result.

'''''''''

```
def validate(type_=str, max_length=50,  contains=['05', '@']):
  def inner(func):
    def wrapper(value, *args, **kwargs):
        if type_ == str:
            print(True)
        else:
            print("Should be string")

        if len(value) > max_length:
            raise ValueError("Please consider Max length!")

        if contains==['05', '@']:
            raise ValueError("Problem!")
        else:
            print(True)

        return func(value, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
  return inner

@validate(type_=str, max_length=50, contains=['05', '@'])
def greet(name):
    print("Welcome, {name}!".format(name=name))

#FOLLOWING ARE SOME SAMPLE INPUTS:
#greet("Ana")
#greet("to Python Programming")
#greet("you")
#greet('johndoe05@gmail.com')
greet('johndoe05@gmail.com')
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: the contain line is not working...idk why and how to fix it if i use: if "05, @" in greet it shows function iteration error

Comment: @Coder - welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please [edit] your question to add some explanation, debugging details or code instead of using comments as you did.